# imagemagick place caption on existing image

Tags: imagemagick

I trying to add a caption to existing image, but it produce two images, one with actuall caption and another just copy of source image... 
Doing it by trying these examples http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#caption

like

```
convert Book.png -background lightblue  -fill blue \
-size 320x   caption:'This is a very long caption line.' \
caption.png
```

result is two images caption-0.png and caption-1.png

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How big is `Book.png` and what does it look like and how is the result supposed to look?

Comment: it is simple  rectangle 536 x 785 pixels
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jjwswb0w756izs8/Book.png?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
convert Book.png ( -size 320x -background lightblue -fill blue caption:"This is a very long caption line." ) -gravity center -composite caption.png
```

I am not sure you can leave out the height of the caption as the font size is calculated to fit the caption bounding box.

Comment: This worked  in the expectable way, `-composite` was the key I guess. And `(`  and `)` I had to remove, otherwise bash was complain `unexpected symbol near (`

Comment: Glad it works and I forgot that windows uses ( ) and Linux uses \( \) but if it works without that's OK. I tend to use parentheses more than required sometimes as it helps when reading the code.